# Street names in OSMNX network maps

Tags: python, gis, osmnx

I am constructing street networks on osmnx using below code.I see that I can print lat/lon information, but

- Is there a way to **include street/road names** in network maps as well? I don't see how to do this in the documentation. Thanks!

  ```
  import osmnx as ox
  G = ox.graph_from_bbox(37.79, 37.78, -122.41, -122.43, network_type='drive')
  G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
  ox.plot_graph(G_projected)
  ```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you annotate your map with OSMnx to show street/road names (or any other edge attributes in the plot). The same logic would apply to labeling nodes instead.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

G = ox.graph_from_address('Piedmont, CA, USA', dist=200, network_type='drive')
G = ox.get_undirected(G)

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor='k', edge_linewidth=3, node_size=0,
                        show=False, close=False)
for _, edge in ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False).fillna('').iterrows():
    c = edge['geometry'].centroid
    text = edge['name']
    ax.annotate(text, (c.x, c.y), c='w')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The only aesthetic challenge being the [label placement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement), which is one of the most difficult problems in computational cartography.