# Is it possible to plot node osmid #'s with the osmnx.plot module?

Tags: python, osmnx

Just wondering if there is an easy way to include node osmids with `osmnx.plot` module.

I tried looking at `osmnx.plot.plot_figure_ground()` and `osmnx.plot.plot_graph()` but it does not seem possible.

I think I could just use `nx.draw()` or something similar but would prefer with osmnx.

Thanks,
Andres

Comment: Did you see the annotation demonstration in the OSMnx usage examples? https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v1.0.1/notebooks/15-advanced-plotting.ipynb

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308690/7321942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599286/7321942

Comment: @gboeing Thank you! I will check them out.